# phonegap error no file uploaded on codeigniter

Tags: android, codeigniter, cordova, image-uploading

I am trying to upload a picture into a server using phonegap and codeigniter on the server side

this is the php code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '1600';
    $config['max_height']  = '1600';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
         echo $error;
        //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        echo "success";
        //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

}
?>

this is the code in phonegap

```
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var params = {};
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://mywebsite.com/upload/do_upload"), win, fail, options, true);
```

this is the logcat

```
03-06 10:29:52.510: D/FileTransfer(5732): upload file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.fileupload.test/cache/1362536991781.jpg to http://soovy.me/upload/do_upload
03-06 10:29:52.510: D/FileTransfer(5732): fileKey: file
03-06 10:29:52.510: D/FileTransfer(5732): fileName: 1362536991781.jpg
03-06 10:29:52.510: D/FileTransfer(5732): mimeType: image/jpeg
03-06 10:29:52.510: D/FileTransfer(5732): params: {"value1":"test","value2":"param"}
03-06 10:29:52.510: D/FileTransfer(5732): trustEveryone: true
03-06 10:29:52.510: D/FileTransfer(5732): chunkedMode: false
03-06 10:29:52.510: D/FileTransfer(5732): headers: null
03-06 10:29:52.510: D/FileTransfer(5732): objectId: 1
03-06 10:29:52.540: D/FileTransfer(5732): String Length: 256
03-06 10:29:52.540: D/FileTransfer(5732): Content Length: 23677
03-06 10:29:54.930: D/FileTransfer(5732): got response from server
03-06 10:29:54.930: D/FileTransfer(5732): <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>
03-06 10:29:54.940: D/CordovaLog(5732): Code = 200
03-06 10:29:54.940: I/Web Console(5732): Code = 200 at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:400
03-06 10:29:54.950: D/CordovaLog(5732): Response = <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>
03-06 10:29:54.950: I/Web Console(5732): Response = <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p> at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:401
03-06 10:29:54.950: D/CordovaLog(5732): Sent = 23421
03-06 10:29:54.950: I/Web Console(5732): Sent = 23421 at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:402
```

however i get a error on php **You did not select a file to upload** but as the logcat states it send 23421 so image was sent. I have also tested the php with a normal form that sends image and it works.

Update:

for anyone else trying to upload from phonegap upload use this code

For normal php from http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap

```
print_r($_FILES); //to check details of file
$new_image_name = "namethisimage.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "./uploads/".$new_image_name);
```

For codeigniter

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))// file should be stated as dakdad answered
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `do_upload` call expects the correct file field name parameter. The default is `userfile` in your example it is `file`. So the line should have been:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file'))
```